# Generating a new DBF file using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, database-design, dbf

I am trying to create a .DBF file using vb.net after figuring out that generating an access DB and afterwards converting it to .DBF was not really possible within vb.net

However, now I am encountering the following problem:

This is the code I am using:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class frmStart
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form



Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

    Dim fd As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim strFileName As String = ""
    Dim dbNameForm As New frmDatabaseName()

    ' init DB Vars
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String


    ' Open Location browser
    dbNameForm.FileName = "Test"
    If dbNameForm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        MsgBox("Select the location where you want your Access-File")

        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim DatabaseFullPath As String = fd.SelectedPath & "\" & dbNameForm.FileName & ".DBF"

            'Create the Database
            CreateDatabase(DatabaseFullPath)
            MsgBox("Database created")

            'Open database
            Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & DatabaseFullPath & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=dBase IV")
            dBaseConnection.Open()
            ' Filling the Database with the required Columns

            sql = "CREATE TABLE DB_Total (NAME varchar(79),TYPE varchar(16), UNIT varchar(31)," &
                    "ADDR varchar(254), RAW_ZERO varchar(11), RAW_FULL varchar(11), ENG_ZERO varchar(11)," &
                    "ENG_FULL varchar(11), ENG_UNITS varchar(8), FORMAT varchar(11), COMMENT varchar(254)," &
                    "EDITCODE varchar(8), LINKED varchar(1), OID varchar(10), REF1 varchar(11), REF2 varchar(11)," &
                    "DEADBAND varchar(11), CUSTOM varchar(128), TAGGENLINK varchar(32), CLUSTER varchar(16)," &
                    "EQUIP varchar(254), ITEM varchar(63), HISTORIAN varchar(6)," &
                    "CUSTOM1 varchar(254), CUSTOM2 varchar(254), CUSTOM3 varchar(254), CUSTOM4 varchar(254)," &
                    "CUSTOM5 varchar(254), CUSTOM6 varchar(254), CUSTOM7 varchar(254), CUSTOM8 varchar(254))"
            Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, dBaseConnection)
            dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dBaseCommand = Nothing

            sql = "CREATE TABLE TagSubs (TAGNAME varchar(79), POLLTIME varchar(6), SCALEMODE varchar(8), DEADBAND varchar(15))"
            dBaseCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, dBaseConnection)
            dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dBaseCommand = Nothing
            dBaseConnection.Close()

        Else

            MsgBox("Action Cancelled")

        End If

    Else

        MsgBox("Action Cancelled")

    End If

End Sub

     ' Creating a Database
Private Function CreateDatabase( _
    ByVal DatabaseFullPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim bAns As Boolean = False
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
    Try

        Dim sCreateString As String = _
          "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
          DatabaseFullPath
        cat.Create(sCreateString)

        bAns = True

    Catch Excep As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

    Finally
        cat = Nothing
    End Try
    Return bAns
End Function

End Class
```

I am also Using a second Form, but that is just a windows in which a user can add a name to the file (Default, the name is "test.DBF" )

After I made this code, and I run it, I get the following error:

```
C:\Documents and settings\HIJ541\Desktop\Test.DBF is not a Valid path. 
Make sure the path name is spelled correctly and there is an active connection 
with the server on which the file is located
```

(Roughly translated from Dutch)

Also, when I try to open the created .DBF file, it will tell me the following:

```
the file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified 
by the file extension
```

I think I am really in over my head on this one.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my own question.

Apparently, when you are connecting to the .DBF file, you are not supposed to enter the full path name( Including the file name)

so:

```
Dim DatabaseFullPath As String = fd.SelectedPath & "\" & dbNameForm.FileName & ".DBF"
```

was supposed to be this:

```
Dim DatabaseFullPath As String = fd.SelectedPath & "\\"
```

Comment: You are correct - I was just about to put that in a comment :)  Don't forget to accept your answer (I think there's a time delay on when you can accept your own answer, so it might be a day or two).